# Screen turns black when trying to install with a intel hd graphics 3000

Tags: intel-graphics

I tried to install Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit from a pen drive. I have an Intel i7 2600k cpu and I use the integrated HD Graphics GPU.

However, the screen always turns black if I select "Run Ubuntu from pendrive" or "Install ubuntu on hdd".

I know that there are some issues with that chip but I don't have any other GPU. So how can I install and run Ubuntu on my system?

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 others main choices:

- http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/ to download the "alternate" version for your architecture
- the use of a minimal version of Ubuntu and later on install all packages you need https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

this are the easiest and quick and dirty solutions for an installation of Ubuntu, there is also a third way via PXE but is more tricky compared to this 2 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot